I want to remove the console display that appears when reloading a script
I want to get rid of the following console printout.

This is the display seen when the script is System Reloaded.
Reloading: <module 'bl_operators' from 'C:\\blender\\stable\\blender-4.1.0-windows-x64\\4.1\\scripts\\startup\\bl_operators\\__init__.py'>
Reloading: <module 'bl_ui' from 'C:\\blender\\stable\\blender-4.1.0-windows-x64\\4.1\\scripts\\startup\\bl_ui\\__init__.py'>
Reloading: <module 'keyingsets_builtins' from 'C:\\blender\\stable\\blender-4.1.0-windows-x64\\4.1\\scripts\\startup\\keyingsets_builtins.py'>
Reloading: <module 'nodeitems_builtins' from 'C:\\blender\\stable\\blender-4.1.0-windows-x64\\4.1\\scripts\\startup\\nodeitems_builtins.py'>

Discussion
First, the file was searched in VSCODE, but no print instruction was found.
Further investigation shows that it seems to be a Reload script for Startup. I don't use startup fundamentally, so I commented out as much code as I could see in the Reload script, but it still didn't go away. （I could only find bl_operators and bl_ui.)
Do you have any idea how to do this?
Does anyone know?
Thank you.

A search in the folder of the VSCODE function with the word
Reloading:
in the folder \startup folder,
the print function appeared.
By commenting this out, the display was disabled.
modules\bpy\utils\__init__.py
-----------------------------

    def test_register(mod):

        if refresh_scripts and mod in original_modules:
            return

        if reload_scripts and mod:
            # print("Reloading:", mod)
            mod = test_reload(mod)

        if mod:
            register_module_call(mod)
            _global_loaded_modules.append(mod.__name__)



